# Edit HTTP requests on the fly

Tags: javascript, http, debugging, firefox, web

I want to edit HTTP requests on the fly
I tried Firefox "Tamper Data" add-on and it is exactly what I want
but the only problem is that it doesn't let me to edit post parameter **name** which I need to do ...

How I can edit POST parameter names in Tamper Data? (And if that's not possible, can it be done without Tamper Data? (for example by editing page source or something else via Firefox developer tools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend you use a free tool called Fiddler:

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

You can write rules to modify requests and responses.  You can also add break points to modify them when you need.  I use this tool every day.

Thanks to @EricLaw for pointing out the custom rule documentation:
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse

And within the Fiddler UI there are tabs for "AutoResponder" and "Inspector" which you can use.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse